# Torch installation error "Found unsuitable version 5.5, but required is at least 6.5"

Tags: linux, torch

I am installing torch in Ubuntu 14.04 Using the following commands and I am getting error after `./install.sh`.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/torch/distro.git ~/torch --recursive
$ cd ~/torch; bash install-deps;
$ ./install.sh
```

Error:

```
Building on 8 cores
-- Found Torch7 in /home/username/torch/install
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:108 (message):
  Could NOT find CUDA: Found unsuitable version "5.5", but required is at
  least "6.5" (found /usr)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:313 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /home/username/torch/install/share/cmake/torch/FindCUDA.cmake:1009 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:7 (FIND_PACKAGE)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/username/torch/extra/cutorch/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

Error: Build error: Failed building.
```

Comment: Does upgrading CUDA to 6.5 helps? you have 5.5

Comment: I have installed cuda 8 and cuDNN 6.5. But still I am getting this error